# What is the purpose of placing () at the end of the function declaration?

Tags: haskell

In week02 Iteration 3 there is a function that has (). What is the purpose of that? Is it so that the function can't be used maliciously?

`mkValidator :: Data -> Data -> Data -> ()`

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: I would also suggest you read this article -> [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 3):

It performs the same kind of utility as void in other programming languages.  It's a unit and is a way of saying that the function doesn't return any value.